# Which alias do I use to run it with another PHP version?

Tags: drush

The Server available for our new Drupal project uses an old PHP CLI Version by default. But I have setup an alias in `.bash_profile` like so:

```
alias php7=/path/to/php7
```

and that is working fine. I would like to use Drush, so I cloned the repository, such that I can use Drush with the PHP version from the alias with `php7 ./path/to/drush`.

Doing so just prints the content of Drush to the terminal.

How can I setup an alias for PHP 7 that allows me to run Drush with that PHP version?

I have added these lines to the .bash_profile file.

```
alias php7=/path/to/php7
export DRUSH_PHP=/path/to/php7
alias drush="php7 $HOME/path/to/drush.phar"
```

When I run `drush pm-update drupal`, I get the following errors.

> The external command could not be executed due to an application error.
>   The command could not be executed successfully
>   Returned: PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in    phar:///path/to/drush.phar/includes/startup.inc on line 63, code: 255)
>   pm-updatestatus failed.

Why? How can I fix that?

Running `drush pm-updatestatus` or `drush cr` works, and `drush status` shows no errors.

Is there a bug in a specific version?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48494/discussion-on-question-by-philipp-drushalias-to-run-it-with-another-php-version).

Answer (score 1):

This is possible by setting the environment variable DRUSH_PHP as described in the documentation.
https://www.drupal.org/node/1302418

Also you can make use of "php" global otpion which allows to specify the absolute path to PHP interpreter.

Comment: Please see my update…

Comment: What does `drush ev 'print PHP_VERSION'` print?

Comment: 7.0.12 -- as expected…

Comment: does drush use composer? On that server is composer installed, but it uses the wrong php version, so there is an alias `composer7=…`, too. might that break it?